# Is there a better way to create a new ArrayList with the result of a forEach with a lambda

Tags: lambda, functional-programming

how can I create a new ArrayList with the result of the items of another List?
The requestAllFieldsList is filled with the content of the WsdlServiceDTOList elements.

```
List<WsdlServiceDTO> wsdlServiceDTOList; 
List<ParameterDTO> requestAllFields = new ArrayList<>();
wsdlServiceDTOList.forEach(wsdlServiceDTO -> this.addRequestFieldsValues(requestAllFields, wsdlServiceDTO));
...
private void addRequestFieldsValues(List<ParameterDTO> requestAllFields, WsdlServiceDTO wsdlServiceDTO){
        long methodId = getServiceOperationId(wsdlServiceDTO);
        wsdlServiceDTO.setServiceOperationId(methodId);
        List<ParameterDTO> requestFields = splitString2List(wsdlServiceDTO.getRequestFields(), methodId );
        requestAllFields.addAll(requestFields);
    }
```

Is there a way to use stream().map() to add each element of the WsdlServiceDTOList to the RequestAllFields array list? Something like the following code:

```
List<ParameterDTO> requestAllFields = wsdlServiceDTOList.stream()
     .map(wsdlServiceDTO -> this.addRequestFieldsValues(wsdlServiceDTO))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
private String addRequestFieldsValues(WsdlServiceDTO wsdlServiceDTO){
        long methodId = getServiceOperationId(wsdlServiceDTO);
        wsdlServiceDTO.setServiceOperationId(methodId);
        List<ParameterDTO> requestFields = splitString2List(wsdlServiceDTO.getRequestFields(), methodId );
        return requestFields ; 
    }
```

I hope some of you have a lambda solution in this case
   enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type in the last method to `Stream<ParameterDTO>` and use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) instead of `map`:

```
private Stream<ParameterDTO> addRequestFieldsValues(WsdlServiceDTO wsdlServiceDTO){
    ...
    List<ParameterDTO> requestFields = splitString2List(wsdlServiceDTO.getRequestFields(), methodId);
    return Stream.of(requestFields);

}

List<ParameterDTO> requestAllFields = wsdlServiceDTOList.stream()
    .flatMap(wsdlServiceDTO -> this.addRequestFieldsValues(wsdlServiceDTO))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`wsdlServiceDTO -> this.addRequestFieldsValues(wsdlServiceDTO)` can also be shortened to `this::addRequestFieldsValues`.

Comment: @gbuyle Then consider accepting it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work